# Disable HTTP client calls for IBM Bluemix Node-RED server API

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, node-red

I am using IBM Bluemix to generate the Node-RED flow. Node-RED code act as the server and client call the Node-RED through API.

Client can call the Bluemix Node-RED server API via both HTTP and HTTPS methods. I need to disable the in-comming HTTP calls.

1. Is that available any methods to disable in-comming HTTP calls via bluemix.setting or etc.
2. I used the function node after the HTTP IN node. Checking headers to identify request is HTTP or HTTPS. If it is HTTP, then set the response headers like below.

   ```
   msg.res.sendStatus(403).send('HTTP disabled')    
   msg.res.sendStatus(403)    
   msg.res.status(403)
   ```

in all the time i am getting

```
Deprecated call to msg.res.sendStatus
Deprecated call to msg.res.status
```

I would like to how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Do you mean you are making all 3 calls listed in option 2 or that you tried each of them?

Comment: I tried one by one. It is blocking HTTP, but issue is getting mentioned warning messages one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. to disabled the admin api, you should set `httpAdminRoot` to `false`. Alternatively, you can use `adminAuth` in order to enable access control on the admin api - http://nodered.org/docs/security
2. In order to respond to an HTTP request received by an `HTTP In` node, you must set the appropriate properties of the message and pass it to an `HTTP Response` node. You must not be call functions of `msg.res` directly - that is deprecated as per the log message you get. The info tab for the `HTTP Response` node describes what properties you can set, including:

   - `payload` is sent as the body of the response
   - `statusCode`, if set, is used as the response status code (default: 200)

For example, your `Function` node would do:

```
msg.statusCode = 403;
msg.payload = "HTTP disabled";
return msg;
```

and then wire that `Function` node to an `HTTP Response` node.

Comment: currently I am having issues with HTTP blocking. adminAuth is working fine.

Comment: I tried to use the statusCode as well.   msg.statusCode = 401; 
      return msg.statusCode; But it is not success. Getting error.  If we cannot access the msg.res, then how can set the statusCode to response ?

Comment: This is how the Node-RED git hub sample defined it. https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/master/nodes/core/io/21-httpin.js?pr=%2Fmetc%2Fnode-red%2Fpull%2F1

Comment: @RuchiraKariyawasam I have updated the answer with an example. You return the full msg object, just with those additional properties set on it.

Comment: Thank you, I just set the msg.statusCode without payload. Now it is working for me.